# Using array_push in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I apologize a head of time for the lengthy/busy question. I am trying to take results from a MySQL query and `base64_encode` the Image blob data, return it to the array and then finally `json_encode` the results so I can use them in my Android application. I know everything on the Android side is set up properly.

What I have is the following:

**PHP/SQL:**

```
$query = "SELECT `locations`.`businessName`, `photos`.`img` 
        FROM `locations` 
        JOIN `photos` ON `locations`.`co_id` = `photos`.`co_id` 
        WHERE `locations`.`businessName` = '".$companyID."'";

    mysql_connect($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());  
    $num = mysql_numrows($result);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $i = 0;
    $rows = array();
    while ($i < $num) {

        $img = mysql_result($result, $i, "img");
        $finalImg['img'] = base64_encode($img);
        $businessName['businessName'] = mysql_result($result, $i, "businessName");

        $finalArray = array_push($rows, $businessName, $finalImg);
        // I know that array_push is pushing each variable as a separate array item
        // I tried creating an alternative variable that amends the two together
        // But that didn't work, result printed [Array, Array] [Array, Array]
        // Was I on the right track?

        $i++;
    }

    print json_encode($rows);
```

**Returns 8 results:**

```
[0] => {
    ["businessName"]=> string(12) "Some Company" }
[1] => {
    ["img"]=> string(145968) "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QIw..." }
```

**What I need:**

I want the results to appear like this, with only 4 results.

```
[0] => {
    ["businessName"] => string(12) "Some Company" 
    ["img"] => string(145968) "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QIw..." }
[1] => {
    ["businessName"] => string(12) "Some Company", 
    ["img"] => string(145968) "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QIw..." }
```

---

**Android Application snippet**:

```
jArray = new JSONArray(result);
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String testerPhoto = jObject.getString("img");
    //Process image. Base64 decode... etc
```

**Android Error:**

```
07-18 11:28:52.573: E/onPostExecute(14562): FAILED: No value for img
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: I didn't know, hadn't needed to look in the manual for awhile on said syntax, thus no red box awareness. I will correct myself. Thanks for the references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
array_push($rows, array_merge($businessName, $finalImg));
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something little that I didn't think of. Thanks. Worked perfectly.

Comment: No problem, all you really needed was array of arrays ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is much simpler:

```
$i = 0;
$rows = array();
while ($i++ < $num) {
    $img = mysql_result($result, $i, "img");
    $rows[] array(
        'businessName' => mysql_result($result, $i, "businessName"),
        'img' => base64_encode($img),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
$rows[] = array(
  'img' => base64_encode($img),
  'businessName' => mysql_result($result, $i, "businessName")
);
```

Or

```
array_push($rows, array_merge($businessName, $finalImg));
```